# Is it safe to submit personal information over a website with a gray (not green) https?

Tags: tls, mixed-content

I am required to submit personal information as part of a form. I looked under developer tools and found this:[![screenshot of item displayed in developer tools][1]][1]

> Mixed Content: The page at `https://example.com` was loaded over a secure connection, but contains a form which targets an insecure endpoint `http://other.example.com`. This endpoint should be made available over a secure connection.

Is it safe to submit personal information over this website?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Information Security! Please do not post text as images. It is harder to read and search.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Danger Will Robinson, Danger!**

The form on the site is *not secure*, and any data sent through that form will be in plain text. This means anyone listening to this communication will have a plain text copy of any data sent to that address.

If you don't know what data is sent there then you can't know if it's safe. Without code review you wouldn't know, and probably shouldn't trust the form. If it sends anything pertaining to secret or PII information, run away. Without a secure connection you can't be sure anyone is getting a copy of your data and should avoid sending it.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the actual request that is sending the form data. That link is HTTP, hence you are in danger. "Mixed content" warnings are given when a website supports HTTPS ony partially, that is it fetches/sends some contents over HTTP, which can be intercepted, sniffed or changed by an attacker.